# ext.net radiogroup get selected items value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I have an Ext.Net Radiogroup and I have to get the selected value and then send that as a parameter to a controller action.  Here is the Directevents I am attempting to use, but it doesnt' seem to work (I get null each time).  Does anyone know how to get the value of the selected item?

```
.DirectEvents(de =>
                            {
                                de.Change.Url = Url.Action("GetItems");
                                de.Change.ExtraParams.Add(new Ext.Net.Parameter
                                {
                                    Name = "Id",
                                    Value = "App.myRadio.getValue() == null ? '0' : App.myRadio.getValue()",
                                    Mode = ParameterMode.Raw
                                });
                            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of all the selected checkboxes/radio buttons on a radio group, you can do:

```
App.myRadio.getChecked();
```

This returns a list of all checkboxes and radio buttons that are selected on the radio group. If you only have radio buttons inside the radio group, it should return an array with just one item.

You can then get the value of the radio button like this:

```
App.myRadio.getChecked().length != 1 ? '0' : App.myRadio.getChecked()[0].getValue();
```

But this will always return a true-ish value (true, 'true', '1' or 'on') for a radio button. If you want the value on the label for that radio button, instead use the following:

```
App.myRadio.getChecked()[0].getFieldLabel()
```

Hope this helps!